# Conflicts between ES1 and ES2 on index mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

For example my script as following:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9201/test1/_mapping/type1' -d '{"type1":{"properties":{"testfd":{"type":"long"}}}}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9201/test1/_mapping/type2' -d '{"type2":{"properties":{"testfd":{"type":"string"}}}}'
```

It threw exception: `The same fields in two mapping types are conflict, one is long and other is string` 
Then I changed the field `testfd` to the same data type `string`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change has been introduced from `ES 2.0`. From the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_conflicting_field_mappings)

> Fields with the same name, in the same index, in different types, **must**
>   have the same mapping, with the exception of the copy_to, dynamic,
>   enabled, ignore_above, include_in_all, and properties parameters,
>   which may have different settings per field.

This was done because fields with the same name in different document types in the same index map to the same Lucene field name internally. Different data types can corrupt your index. [This blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring) explains everything in detail.

Hope this helps!